# What is the html tag condition for Windows Live Mail 2012±?

Tags: html, email, windows-live-mail

I Had a lot of problem with this email client especially for responsive email and I haven't found what is the condition like for Outlook :

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style>
/* Target Outlook 2007 and 2010 */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Any idea or resources to be redirect to?